# Getting the current users details with Passport js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, passport.js

I am using Passport js with Express and am confused about getting the current user's details within different components of the app.

I would like to get the username and put it into an array when a user connects to a socket. In my server.js, I am requiring my routes and socket.io file.

```
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);
require('./app/sockets.js').listen(server, passport);
```

In my socket.js file I am having some events when the user connects.

```
var users = [];
exports.listen = function(server, passport){
    var socketio = require('socket.io');
    io = socketio.listen(server);

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        users.push({
            id: socket.id
        });
        socket.emit('new user', socket.id);
        console.log('user count: ' + io.engine.clientsCount);
        console.log('users length: ' + users.length);

        socket.on('send message', function(message){
            if (/\S/.test(message)) {
                io.sockets.emit('new message', message);
                console.log('new message: ' + message);
            }
        });
         socket.on('disconnect', function(socket){
             console.log('user disconnected: ' + users.length);
             users.splice(users.indexOf(socket.id), 1);
         });
    });
};
```

I can get the username inside the routes file and pass it onto the view. I am confused about how to get a details from the session with a file that doesn't have a request. such as:

```
app.get('/chat', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
        res.render('chat.ejs',{
            user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });

    });
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get the user from code that wasn't executed by a route?

Comment: I'm asking how I can get the current user from the session in the socket.js file and other files.

Comment: `sockets`, on a programming level, are not `socket.io` related... I removed the tag. See the [tag:sockets] tag details for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The [passport.socketio](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio) project on GitHub may be the solution.